# Use two-finger right click in Plasma

Tags: touchpad, kde, plasma, libinput

I'm on Kubuntu 18.04 and would like to use two-finger right click. In System Settings the touchpad settings are greyed out, even though I'm on Plasma 5.12. How can I enable two-finger right click?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the situation as I understand it, though I'm no expert. After 2 decades of being standard on laptops, touchpads are finally supported in the kernel. Therefore, the synaptics driver isn't automatically installed. However, if you open the muon packagae manager, search on synaptic and install this driver, you may find that missing options return in KDE. I did. -GEF

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04 with hwe, vertical scrolling using the right hand edge of the touchpad suddenly stopped working (maybe after an update?) - has been working fine since I installed 18.04 in April '18. This fixed it, thanks!